# AWS ElastiCache redis and maxmemory

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I'm running AWS Elasticache Redis configured with a node type cache.r5.xlarge.  Per the configuration, the maxmemory should be 28261849702 (28G).  This is gotten from

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html#ParameterGroups.Redis.NodeSpecific

However when connecting to the redis endpoint, it's showing only 19G:

(from the 'info' command)

```
# Memory
...
maxmemory:21196387277
maxmemory_human:19.74G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
...
```

I'm wondering if anyone can explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 3):

Found the reason for this:
There's a reserved-memory-percent defaulting to 25 (percent).
This is an AWS-specific thing, not part of Redis itself.